# "Vagrant up" stuck verifying Hyper-v provider

Tags: windows, virtualbox, vagrant

When running `vagrant up` it is stuck `verifying Hyper-V provider...`

In windows 7 64-bit after installing Vagrant and Oracle virtual box.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox` to your PATH environment variable in Windows.

Comment: useful question and answer

Comment: Hi,
I am trying to run the tutorial http://technologyconversations.com/2015/02/11/continuous-integration-delivery-or-deployment-with-jenkins-docker-and-ansible/
and it's stuck as well: "cd: Verifying Hyper-V is enabled..."
there's no oracle VB AFAIK ...
any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

If the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23970639/2504766) proposed by ESP does not work for You (that was my case unfortunately) try setting environmental variable `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER` to `virtualbox`.

Comment: Thanks!  I had to add the environment variable that you listed, but it did the trick.

However, it revealed a new issue.  I have VirtualBox 5 installed, and as of July 10, 2015, Vagrant does not support VB5.

So, here's some helpful links for others in a similar situation.

Link to download VirtualBox 4.3:
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3

Link to a conversation about a work around to make VirtualBox 5 work with Vagrant:
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5572

Comment: That was it! type `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER=virtualbox vagrant up` and see if vagrant complains that _The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine 'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system._

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, and after a while the problem was that I was using a newer version of virtual box for vagrant.

I've downgraded virtual box for version 4.3 and vagrant for version 1.7.2

(As Suggested by Ethan Strider)

Answer (score 0):

Even after setting environment variable, if your provider doesn't change to virtualbox from hyper-v then, you can give vagrant up command as -:

```
vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```